# Object defined error in VBA - code continues to run afterwards

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a report generating tool in Excel using OLAP data transcribed to pivottables. As using slicers in the past affected performance of the file very negatively, I am now attempting to implement it using macro's to set filter values. The code below sets a filter on the month level, using a year (FilterYear), month (FilterMonth), Pivottable name (PivotTable) and worksheet containing the table (SheetCase).

The problem I've been having is that, while iterating over the tables, I get random "object or application defined errors" on the first ".VisibleItemsList" statement. These do not always appear in the same iteration and furthermore, when I hit "continue" the macro just continues running until the next time this error pops up (also randomly). Continuing like this finishes the code and it will have done everything it's supposed to do, but the error messages are a real nuissance.

I found that using "with" statements could help resolve this issue ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565829/random-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-1004-pastespecial-met)), which is why I added the worksheet parameter in the sub (before I just used ActiveSheet), but this does not resolve the issue. Has anyone had any problems like this before? I am happy to provide more information if needed. Thank you very much in advace for any help you might be able to give.

```
Sub FilterPivotFieldMonth(FilterYear As Integer, FilterMonth As Integer, PivotTable As String, SheetCase As Worksheet)

' Macro to filter PivotTable according to FilterYear and FilterMonth
 With SheetCase
    .PivotTables(PivotTable).PivotFields( _
    "[Date and Time].[By Year].[Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    .PivotTables(PivotTable).PivotFields( _ 
    "[Date and Time].[By Year].[Month]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Date and Time].[By Year].[Month].&[" & FilterMonth & " / " & FilterYear & "]")
    .PivotTables(PivotTable).PivotFields( _
    "[Date and Time].[By Year].[Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    .PivotTables(PivotTable).PivotFields( _
    "[Date and Time].[By Year].[Hour]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    .PivotTables(PivotTable).PivotFields( _
    "[Date and Time].[By Year].[Quarter Hour]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone would be looking for a solution: instead of giving the worksheet as an input parameter, I used the sheet number (integer). This seems to have gotten rid of the error all together. Line for now reads:

```
With Sheets(SheetCase)
```

Still don't know why Excel gave me a hard time there, but at least it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the filter in your pivot has the selection "multiple item" checked. [filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdiDi.png)

If it is unchecked probably you cannot use the method .Visibleitemlist and that might cause an error.